# How do you consume an OCX in a class library?

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-4.0, activex, ocx

My goal is to consume an OCX inside of a VB.NET 4.0 class library in VS 2013, so that I may access a device exposed by the OCX from multiple applications via the class library.  I have tried adding a reference directly to the OCX, but it just adds an Interop.XXXLib.dll which only provides an interface.  I have also tried the OCX to my toolbox, adding a windows form to my class library, dropping the toolbox activeX control on the win form, and exposing that active x control to my class through a public property.  However, this later method requires that I use static members and the first app that uses the device won't release the resources, so that other apps may use the device.

Your help with this problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is all pretty normal, the VB6 usage model.  Contact the vendor, surely they've got something better by now.